# Android does not respond to soft back keys in Phonegap build

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, zepto

Simply put, I have an onscreen back key in my phonegap application. It works for every device except android, and I would assume this is because the back button isnt even *needed* on android because of the hard key.

But for build simplicity, I'd like to include it anyway. Is there something special that is needed to be done to make the back key act as the hardware back key?

NOTE: Using zepto. Here is my current back button handler:

```
     $( '.back' ).click( function() { 
      window.history.back();
  });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to call:

```
navigator.app.backHistory();
```

instead of window.history.back();